# How to insert mutliple where clauses into an SQL string

Tags: java, sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using an Azure Cosmos NoSQL database with SQL syntax. How do I create an SQL string that can dynamically add more WHERE statements? For example, I want to be able to not have to code in "WHERE f.%s=@val" for one and then hardcode another function with "WHERE f.%s=@val1 AND f.%s=@val2" if I have two where statements. I want to have up to 7 WHERE statements.

Below I have code that queries for one property (one WHERE statement) and another one that queries for 2 properties (two WHERE statements). There is a lot of hard coding involved. The lines with queryString is where I'm having trouble.

```
public Iterable<Document> queryForOneProperty(String databaseName, String 
    collectionName, String key, String val) {

    FeedOptions queryOptions = getDefaultFeedOptions();
    String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", databaseName, collectionName);

    SqlParameterCollection paramCollection = new SqlParameterCollection();
    paramCollection.add(new SqlParameter("@val", val));
    SqlQuerySpec query = new SqlQuerySpec(String.format("SELECT * FROM %s f WHERE f.%s = @val", collectionName, key), paramCollection);

    return query;
}

public Iterable<Document> queryForTwoProperties(String databaseName, String 
    collectionName, String[] keys, String[] vals) {

    FeedOptions queryOptions = getDefaultFeedOptions();
    String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", databaseName, collectionName);

    SqlParameterCollection paramCollection = new SqlParameterCollection();
    paramCollection.add(new SqlParameter("@val1", vals[0]));
    paramCollection.add(new SqlParameter("@val2", vals[1]));
    String queryString = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s f WHERE f.%s = @val1 AND f.%s = @val2", collectionName, keys[0], keys[1]);
    SqlQuerySpec query = new SqlQuerySpec(queryString, paramCollection);

    return query;
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bogus first condition and then only add AND ...

```
String condition = "WHERE 1 = 1";

if (some logic) {
    condition += " AND x = 42";
}
```

Here is a simple example of a query factory method

```
private final static String BASE_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM %s f WHERE 1 = 1";

public static String queryBuilder(String ... conditions) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(BASE_QUERY);
    for (String condition : conditions) {
        builder.append(" ");
        builder.append(condition);      
     }
     return builder.toString();
}
```

Example

```
System.out.println(queryBuilder("AND f.%s = @val1", "AND f.%s = @val2"));
System.out.println(queryBuilder("AND f.%s = @val1"));
System.out.println(queryBuilder());
```

gives

> SELECT * FROM %s f WHERE 1 = 1 AND f.%s = @val1 AND f.%s = @val2
>   SELECT * FROM %s f WHERE 1 = 1 AND f.%s = @val1
>   SELECT * FROM %s f WHERE 1 = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this  use is null

```
SELECT * FROM %s f WHERE (@val1 is null or f.%s = @val1) AND (@val2 is null or f.%s = @val2)
```

Comment: You are not reading it correctly it is @param1 is null or then it checks the param against the query.